# What are the best ways to prevent an O(n) callback in Node.js from blocking the event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, event-loop

I am working on a node server for a basic social media application. It supports basic CRUD operations for posts, comments, and likes. My next feature is a notification service that broadcasts notifications to many users at once. As an example, it looks something like:

```
function createNotifications(users) {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    createNotification(user);
  }
}

function createNotification(user) {
  db.save //save new notification in DB;
  sendNotificationToUser(user.socketId);
}
```

As the length of users increases, the createNotifications function time increases linearly, blocking the event loop while executing. What would be the best way to offload this work so as to not block the event loop? It does not seem like there is a good way to do this natively in node. I'm considering creating a separate microservice for notifications, or using something like kafka. To summarize my question, typically, in node, what strategies are used to offload CPU heavy services that are non-constant.

EDIT:
Having reviewed similar threads, I think my preferred native js solution is:

```
async function createNotifications(users) {
  for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    await createNotification(users[i]);
  }
}

async function createNotification(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      resolve();
      db.save; //save new notification in DB
      sendNotificationToUser(user.socketId);
    })
  })
}
```

The forloop is preferable here compared to a forEach, as it is non-blocking and works with await, whereas forEach will run synchronously for every user. I also chose to use setImmediate rather than await the db save so that each createNotification can run in immediate succession.

Comment: How many users are we talking about here?

Comment: "*My next feature is a notification service that broadcasts notifications to many users at once.  […] CPU heavy services that are non-constant.*" - uh, the example code you've shown is not CPU-heavy at all, it's mostly doing database calls and sending socket messages.

Comment: @Bergi Up theoretically up to 50,000

Comment: @Bergi would you not consider a 50,000 index loop CPU-heavy?

Comment: Not really (the loop itself takes around 5ms on my machine), and not compared to 50000 database accesses :-) And I suspect you have other problems already if your server keeps 50000 open websocket connections at the same time. And in your example, the solution is relatively trivial: `await` the asynchronous database calls, so the iteration of the array is not synchronous and won't block the event loop.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. Makes sense. Because my createNotification uses an I/O process (the DB save), I can await it without blocking my event loop. So the revised code would look like:
`function createNotifications(users) {
  users.forEach((user) => {
    await createNotification(user);
  }
}
async function createNotification(user) {
  await db.save
  await sendNotificationToUser(user.socketId);
  return;
}`
Suppose though my inner forloop function did not fire off any async events, how do I prevent such a loop from blocking?

Comment: A crude way to do it, the inner function could look like:
`async function createNotification(user) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => {
doSomeSynchronousTask(user);
resolve();
}, 0)
})
}`

Comment: The post has been update to include these points with a better example @Bergi

Answer (score 0):

like you said, you can create a queue in another process to handle the work. then the main process's event loop won't be overloaded.

Whichever technique you use, the principle is always the same.

- you can use workers.
- you can fork.
- you can use a microservice.

Answer (score 0):

The modification you propose is on the right track, but note:

- `createNotifications` is async now, also, and must be declared and
  called as such.
- await-ing in the loop will sequentialize the
  notifications unnecessarily. Unless the notifications depend on each
  other these can be run concurrently.

Modifying your proposal accordingly...

```
async function createNotifications(users) {
  let promises = users.map(user => createNotification(user))
  return Promise.all(promises)
}

// presuming that db.save and sendNotificationToUser both return promises
async function createNotification(user) {
  const notification = // create the data for notification
  return Promise.all([
   db.save(notification),
   sendNotificationToUser(user.socketId)
  ]);
}
```

If the `db.save` or `sendNotificationToUser` do not themselves return promises, wrap them in async functions like this...

```
// suppose a db save method with callbacks for success and error
async function dbSave_Q(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.save(data, resolve, reject);
    // more verbose, but clearer...
    // db.save(data, result => resolve(result), error => reject(error));    
  })
}

// suppose a "Notifier" object with an 'on' pattern
async function sendNotificationToUser_Q(user) {
  const notifier = new Notifier(user.socketId)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    notifier.on('success', result => { resolve(result) })
    notifier.on('error', error => { reject(error) })
  })
}
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, I'm not interested in the result of createNotifications, I just want all the notifications to be created without blocking the event loop for the duration of a potentially long loop. The issue I see with this approach, is that the users.map() still runs synchronously as it creates the promises array. If the users array is many thousands of items long, this map will hold up my main thread for several seconds. @danh

Comment: Hi @Liam, promise.all returns an array of results corresponding to the resolutions of the input promises. It’s good practice to return that array along the call chain, and up to the caller to ignore it or not. About the map creating promises, that’s just a loop of fast operations. It will block execution, but no more than any thousands-long loop of O(1) sync operations, ie hardly at all.

Comment: Remember, in that map, we’re not doing the operations, we’re creating promises to do them.

Comment: thanks for these tips - surprisingly, my array map was taking much longer than expected. To test it simply, I changed createNotification to: `return new Promise((resolve) => {
console.log('inside promise'); 
await dbAsyncHelper(); 
resolve();}`. To my surprise, the console.log was executing during the .map, causing createNotifications to hang on the promises initialization. Not sure why this is the case, but it's more clear to me now that console.logs are expensive, especially in long loops.

Comment: One other observation, as you pointed out, my edited code sequentializes the promises, all be it in immediate succession, whereas your suggestion calls the promises in parallel. One issue I foresee with the parallel promises, is that the callback queue is likely to pile high with messages, which will hold up any other incoming requests as the many thousand callbacks are executed. With the sequentialization method, the callback queue seems to get less overloaded so as to keep the event loop open to accommodate other requests. @danh

Comment: The code you changed to can’t be right. If dbAsyncHelper can be awaited, then it must return a promise and shouldn’t be wrapped in new Promise. It also shouldn’t be awaited unless you want to sequence the db calls. I don’t think you do, and I think your worry about the “callback queue” is unfounded. I think you should get the basics understood on a smaller data set, then move on to issues caused by scale, if you encounter any. So far, I believe the latency you’ve been seeing is due to misunderstanding about promise code and concurrency, not scale.

Comment: my confusion was not realizing that the Promise constructor is called immediately (synchronously). I wrapped the dbAsyncHelper in a new Promise to better simulate my actual createNotification function which awaits several async calls. Moreover, any synchronous events in a Promise constructor, **before** another promise is returned or awaited, will be pushed to the top of the stack. I realize this is fairly obvious in hindsight. Although I may be getting ahead of myself thinking about scale, if many thousand async callbacks begin executing one on top of another, the event loop will...

Comment: ...be handling those __microtasks__, and cannot resume handling other requests until the microtask queue is empty. But the tricky thing is, if callbacks are piling onto that queue faster than they are being processed (perhaps this is worsened by my inclusion of logs), new requests will have to wait until all the callbacks have finishing executing.
For reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-wildflower-yg6ry?file=/src/index.js